# How to filter an array of objects using another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I want to filter one array of objects using another array of objects, like in the following code snippet:

```js
const entries = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Entry 1",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 101,
        name: "topic 1.1",
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        name: "topic 1.2",
      },
      {
        id: 103,
        name: "topic 1.3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Entry 2",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 201,
        name: "topic 2.1",
      },
      {
        id: 202,
        name: "topic 2.2",
      },
      {
        id: 203,
        name: "topic 2.3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Entry 3",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 25,
        name: "topic 3.1",
      },
      {
        id: 26,
        name: "topic 3.2",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const filters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    topics: [
      {
        id: 101,
      },
      {
        id: 102,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    topics: [],
  },
];

const result = entries
  .filter(({ id, topics }) =>
    filters.some(
      ({ id: idFromFilteres, topics: topicsFromFilters }) =>
        idFromFilteres === id && topicsFromFilters.length > 0,
    ),
  )
  .map(({ id, topics, ...rest }) => ({
    id,
    topics: topics?.filter(({ id: topicId }) =>
      filters.some(({ topics: topicsFromFilter }) =>
        topicsFromFilter.some(
          ({ id: topicIdFromFilter }) => topicIdFromFilter === topicId,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ...rest,
  }));

console.log(result);
```

The code is working fine, but I don't like how I'm iterating again the `entries` array to filter the `topics`; notice also that entries with empty `topics` get filtered as well.

Is there a way to filter this array using a single iteration?

Comment: Sounds like a reduce could do that

Comment: why output does not contain id 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array::reduce()` to filter and map simultaneously:

```js
const result = entries.reduce((r, entry) => {
  const found = filters.find(({ id }) => entry.id === id);
  if (found) {
    const topics = entry.topics.filter(({ id }) => found.topics.some((topic) => topic.id === id));
    topics.length && r.push({...entry, topics});
  }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const entries = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Entry 1",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 101,
        name: "topic 1.1",
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        name: "topic 1.2",
      },
      {
        id: 103,
        name: "topic 1.3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Entry 2",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 201,
        name: "topic 2.1",
      },
      {
        id: 202,
        name: "topic 2.2",
      },
      {
        id: 203,
        name: "topic 2.3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Entry 3",
    topics: [
      {
        id: 25,
        name: "topic 3.1",
      },
      {
        id: 26,
        name: "topic 3.2",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const filters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    topics: [
      {
        id: 101,
      },
      {
        id: 102,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    topics: [],
  },
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `filter` and `map` functions:

```js
// to map filter topics to entry IDs.
const map = new Map(filters.map((filter) => [filter.id, filter.topics.map((topic) => topic.id)]));

const result = entries.filter((entry) => {
  const topics = map.get(entry.id);
  return topics && topics.length > 0;
}).map((entry) => {
  const topics = map.get(entry.id);
  entry.topics = entry.topics.filter((topic) => topics.includes(topic.id));
  return entry;
});
```

- `filter`: remove entries without matching filter topics
- `map`: filter topics for the remaining entries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to to iterate over the entries array and filter it based on the filters array.

Example:

```
const result = entries.reduce((filteredEntries, entry) => {
  const matchingFilter = filters.find((filter) => filter.id === entry.id);

  if (matchingFilter) {
    const filteredTopics = entry.topics.filter((topic) =>
      matchingFilter.topics.some((filterTopic) => filterTopic.id === topic.id),
    );

    if (filteredTopics.length > 0) {
      filteredEntries.push({ ...entry, topics: filteredTopics });
    }
  }

  return filteredEntries;
}, []);
```